# Where did endianness come from

Tags: computer-science, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are both little- and big-endian in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752715/why-are-both-little-and-big-endian-in-use)

I am just wondering what is the history of endianness? I would have thought that the way that binary data was stored at lowest level would have long become standard yet clearly it has not. Why?

Comment: That's the thing about endianness -- we have more than one standard, started (I believe) by different computer manufacturers.

Comment: To whoever voted to close: how is this actually off topic? It's a very interesting question I'd say.

Comment: Both big and little endianness have their advantages and disadvantages, so neither one is necessarily "better" then the other.

Comment: @tony-the-tiger It is more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Tony: It's a dupe, though, Paul is right.

Answer (score 8):

The term actually came from Gulliver's Travels, but was adopted to summarise the seemingly arbitrary difference in number representation in computers:

> The origin of the odd terms big endian
>   and little endian can be traced to the
>   1726 book Gulliver's Travels, by
>   Jonathan Swift. In one part of the
>   story, resistance to an imperial edict
>   to break soft-boiled eggs on the
>   "little end" escalates to civil war.
>   (The plot is a satire of England's
>   King Henry VIII's break with the
>   Catholic Church.) A few hundred years
>   later, in 1981, Danny Cohen applied
>   the terms and the satire to our
>   current situation in IEEE Computer
>   (vol. 14, no. 10).

http://www.netrino.com/node/149

Answer (score 4):

I would start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It has to do with optimization it seems. Some calculations are easier with big-endian, while others are easier with little-endian.

Little-endian

> The little-endian system has the property that the same value can be read from memory at different lengths without using different addresses

Big-endian

> On the other hand, in some situations it may be useful to obtain an approximation of a multi-byte or multi-word value by reading only its most-significant portion instead of the complete representation; a big-endian processor may read such an approximation using the same base-address that would be used for the full value.

Answer (score -1):

You might just as well ask why every single protein in existance is built up from L-aminoacids instead of the perfectly similar (but mirrored) D-aminoacids. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid#Isomerism

Some things just happen for no reason at all and then stick due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: Or you can actually have a look at the reason why there are 2 different versions and learn something...

Comment: Man, should have remembered noone here is a biologist ^^

Comment: Haha, as a biochemist, I thought this was funny... It's not entirely true, though. Only *most* proteins are built from L-isomers. And I don't think etymology is rooted in quite the same evolutionary lottery as biology.

Comment: +1 to compensate for people with no sense of humor and no appreciation for a good analogy.