# usage of const in c++

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, constants

I am new to C++.I was going through a C++ book and it says

```
const int i[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
float f[i[3]]; // Illegal
```

It says the declaration of the float variable is invalid during compilation.Why is that?

Suppose if we use

```
int i = 3;
float f[i];
```

It works.

What is the problem with the first situation?

Thanks.

Comment: your second case is illegal too. Note that *it works* and *legal* are too different things!

Comment: @Walter two different things, even...

Comment: @twalberg could be interpreted as "the difference between them is too big to ignore"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the first is illegal because an array must have a compile-time known bound, and `i[3]`, while strictly speaking known at compile time, does not fulfill the criteria the language sets for "compile-time known".

The second is also illegal for the same reason.

Both cases, however, will generally be accepted by GCC because it supports C99-style runtime-sized arrays as an extension in C++. Pass the `-pedantic` flag to GCC to make it complain.

**Edit:** The C++ standard term is "integral constant expression", and things qualifying as such are described in detail in section 5.19 of the standard. The exact rules are non-trivial and C++11 has a much wider range of things that qualify due to `constexpr`, but in C++98, the list of legal things is, roughly:

- integer literals
- simple expressions involving only constants
- non-type template parameters of integral type
- variables of integral type declared as `const` and initialized with a constant expression

Comment: Can you through some light on compile-time known bound please..Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your second example doesn't work and it shouldn't work.
`i` must be constant. This works

```
const int i = 3;
float f[i];
```

Comment: It will *work* (that is, both compile and perform as expected) on some compilers (e.g. gcc) if certain flags are not set (e.g. -pedantic).  That does not mean it is legal according to the standard, however.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. `const int const i[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` doesn't work also, at least in Visual Studio 2010. As I understand, it would be `constexpr` in C++11.

Comment: It would depend on the usage (in this case, it would still be `const`).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables for the difference between `const` and `constexpr`

Answer (score 2):

Just to expound on Sebastian's answer:

When you create a static array, the compiler must know how much space it needs to reserve.  That means the array size *must* be known at compile-time.  In other words, it must be a literal or a constant:

```
const int SIZE = 3;
int arr[SIZE]; // ok

int arr[3]; // also ok

int size = 3;
int arr[size]; // Not OK
```

Since the value of `size` could be different by the time the array is created, the oompiler won't know how much space to reserve for the array.  If you declare it as `const`, it knows the value will not change, and can reserve the proper amount of space.

If you need an array of a variable size, you will need to create it dynamically using `new` (and make sure to clean it up with `delete` when you are done with it).

Comment: the 1st should be `constexpr int SIZE = 3;`, no?

Comment: @BЈовић `3` is not an expression:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11

Answer (score 0):

For arrays with lengths known only at runtime in C++ we have `std::vector<T>`. For builtin arrays the size must be known at compile-time. This is also true for C++11, although the much older C99-standard already supports dynamic stack arrays.  See also the accepted answer of [Why doesn't C++ support dynamic arrays on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458857/why-doesnt-c-support-dynamic-arrays-on-the-stack)