# How to convert C to C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

How can I convert C code to C++?  When I try my best, I failed every time.
Can anyone help me?

In particular, I'm trying to understand the following:

> `v=v%10?v%(5*r)*n--:v/10`

I know if `v == v mod 10,v%(5*r)*n--`. if not, `v/10`.  But I don't understand `v%(5*r)*n--`.

Here's the code in context:

```
long v=1,r=1e9;
main(n){
    for(scanf("%d",&n);v=v%10?v%(5*r)*n--:v/10;n||printf("%d",v%r));
    }
```

Comment: C++ is derived from C, you can run C code on C++ but not the other way around.

Comment: A source code that is written in C is already a C++ code. Just change the extension of the file to .cpp

Comment: Not all C is C++! There are differences, but most straightforward C code can be compiled directly as C++. Not sure about this, need to make sense of it first. Not sure it is valid C in the first place. C requires an explicit `return` from `main`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Yup, you're right. Maybe I was being a little too strict with my wording

Comment: @Sacert http://stackoverflow.com/a/31505447/1870760 Anyways, this code looks like this will compile on a C++ compiler too.

Comment: @JameyD I guess this is what I get for dumping C for C++ early on, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Immediately stop reading that blog.

Comment: That code is utterly dreadful. Please please please stop trying to learn from whomever wrote it.

Comment: "I failed every time" is not a scientific problem description suitable for SO.

Comment: Getting that to compile should be trivial, but if you're a beginner you should stay away from "code golf" blogs. (The code is awful; if you used that at work, you'd be looking for another job soon.)

Comment: Incidentally, the test is "if v%10 is zero", not "if v%10 is v"

Answer (score 0):

This C expression is also valid in C++. Expression `v%(5*r)*n--` is equivalent to expression `v % ((5*r)*(n--))` due to operator precedence rules. Postfix decrement operator `--`(it decreases a variable by one) will evaluate first, what remains is an expression of type `A % B * C`. Since operators `%` (remainder) and `*` (multiplication) are on the same precedence level, left to right associativity rule will be applied. Therefore, we have `v % ((5*r)*(n--))`. For more information check out these links:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

You also do no understand the ternary operator. In your case, the whole statement `v=v%10?v%(5*r)*n--:v/10` means: if `v%10` is true (different from zero) then assign result of `v%(5*r)*n--` to variable `v`, otherwise assign result of `v/10` to variable `v`. For more information check out

http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html

Btw, please note that the person writing this blog produces some awful code. You probably do not want to learn from it.

Comment: Your answer would be good if you hadn't mixed up left and right and thus gave the wrong parenthesis for the equivalent expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for `main` is bad.  C++ does not allow implicit typing for functions<sup>1</sup>, and `main` takes either zero or two arguments;  it should be written as

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  ...
}
```

if the program takes any command line arguments<sup>2</sup> and

```
int main( void )
{
  ...
}
```

if it doesn't<sup>3</sup>.

The expression `v=v%10?v%(5*r)*n--:v/10` is equally valid (if unspeakably ugly) in C and C++, so that's not an issue.

The expression `n||printf("%d",v%r)` is a bit of a head-scratcher, though; what do you think it's trying to accomplish?

**Edit**

Sorry, wasn't quite awake when I wrote that last bit.  Obviously, the intent of that expression is to only write the value of `v%r` when `n` is 0.

The `||` is the logical-or operator - the expression `a || b` evaluates to 1 if either `a` or `b` is non-zero, or 0 if both `a` and `b` are zero.  The operator *short-circuits*; if `a` is non-zero, then the result of `a || b` is 1 regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` won't be evaluated at all.

Thus, in the expression `n || printf( "%d", v%r )`, if `n` is non-zero, then the `printf` call won't be executed.

Note that the line

```
for(scanf("%d",&n);v=v%10?v%(5*r)*n--:v/10;n||printf("%d",v%r));
```

is *hideous*; even with some whitespace it would be hard to follow and debug.  This should not be taken as an example of good code.  That style of programming is only suitable for the [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/), except that it's not ugly *enough* for that particular competition.

A better way to write it for C++ would be

```
#include <iostream>

int main( void )
{
  long v=1,r=1e9; // no reason to make these global
  int n;

  if ( std::cin >> n )
  {    
    while ( v ) // v != 0
    {
      if ( v % 10 )
        v = v % (5 * r) * n--; // whitespace is your friend, use it
      else
        v = v / 10;

      if ( n ) // n != 0
        std::cout << v % r;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cerr << "Error while reading \"n\"...try again" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1.  Neither does C since the 1999 standard, and it's bad practice anyway.

2.  You don't have to use the names `argc` and `argv`, although they are the common convention.

3.  Implementations *may* provide additional signatures for `main` (such as extra arguments in addition to `argc` and `argv`), but those additional signatures must be documented; don't assume any random signature is going to be valid.</sup>

Comment: Sadly, your _better way to write it for C++_ yields results different from the C version.