# C/C++ implicit void* cast with malloc

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

The question on following snippet of code

```
  char *p = malloc(10);
```

When i compile it with **gcc** with any `-std=`, this does compile well.

But with **g++** with any `-std=` this does produce error:

```
w.c:4:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  char *p = malloc(10);
```

Why behavior is differing? I thought all lines which compile in C should compile with C++ compiler, too. Is there any standard requirements for this?

Comment: Simple answer: No. C++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: " I thought all lines which compile in C should compile with C++ compiler, " - why would you think that?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31505447/417501) for more examples where C and C++ disagree.

Comment: @M.M Stroustrup's overview says "Except for minor details, C++ has C as a subset" http://www.stroustrup.com/crc.pdf

Comment: @PSIAlt, not so minor if legal `C` code doesn't compile as `C++`, *by design* :)

Comment: @PSIAlt, also note that the document you linked to is a 17 year old work. Much has changed since for both `C` and `C++`.

Comment: @StoryTeller i think this does not matter, this code does not compile with **g++** even with `-std=c++98`

Comment: @PSIAlt, true, but my point was that the difference between the languages only grew since.

Comment: @PSIAlt hard to believe as it is, C++98 was 18 years ago - older than the document you referred to :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you compile as `C` with `gcc` and as `C++` with `g++`.
Those are different languages.

`C++` is more strongly typed as far as implicit conversions from `void*` go.

Comment: "C++ has stricter type checking" is an urban legend...   the difference in this case is that C has implicit conversion from `void *` to other object pointer types , nothing more and nothing less.  Both languages are statically typed, and both languages offer the conversion - just one language requires a cast.

Comment: @M.M, to be pedantic for a second, requiring a cast *is* a stricter position on language designers part. And you most definitely shouldn't take the first half of that sentence without the second.

Comment: @StoryTeller I agree with you but, to be just as pedantic, the requirement for an explicit cast in this case would normally described as an example of _stronger typing_ rather than _stricter type checking_, I think.

Comment: @davmac, point taken, and corrected.

Comment: @M.M statically typing is not related with strong typing.

Answer (score 4):

First of all it is explicit in specification of those 2 languages and it is enough for compilers to conform to that.

But there are good reasons why C allows implicit conversion from pointer to any to void * and back while C++ disallows it. As C as no inheritance support, all kind of polymorphism requires the use of `void *` pointers. So conversion to and from `void *` is assumed to be a common use case. Also as you have no static, dynamic or const cast in C, if you want to keep constness of a pointer, you would have to repeat it on each `void *`conversion.

But C++ does have inheritance, static and dynamic cast. So conversion from pointer to any to `void *` and back has less common use cases and for that reason must be explicit. And last but not least, the usage of `new` hides the call to malloc and directly gives a pointer to the proper type avoiding the cast form `void *` each time you create a dynamic object.

Comment: More importantly IMHO, C++ has `new` which renders `malloc` - and any associated type conversion, explicit or otherwise - redundant.

Comment: @davmac: not redundant, as `new` itself may use `malloc`. It provides a higher abstraction by also calling the constructor, etc..

Comment: @Olaf redundant from the point of the view of the application programmer. (And btw you can use `new char [xxx]` if you want to allocate memory without calling constructors - so `new` gives you everything `malloc` does and more).

Comment: @Olaf grammar/typo error in your comment? I don't understand it. Anyway, my point is that you can use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free` universally (or almost so). They both allocate storage. In this sense, there is redundancy.

Comment: @davmac: Sorry, retry: There's _more_ to "application programming" than PCs.

Comment: @Olaf Ok. My point was that an application programmer doesn't need to know or care whether `new` is actually implemented via `malloc` (in response to your "not redundant, as new itself may use malloc"). I wasn't referring to PCs in particular. I'm talking about what the programmer uses, not what happens under the surface.

Comment: @davmac: While I generally agree C++ should not use `malloc`, there might be reasons to use `malloc` in C++ on an embedded system. Using `new char [xxx]` is not really a better solution.

Comment: @davmac: IMHO, a typical use case for using malloc in a C++ program (except for some embedded systems that could have *special* implementations) is when you have to be called through a C API that requires a malloc'ed block of memory that will be free'd after use. Of course, `new char[x]` could be used, but if you know that `free` will be directly called, it is better to use `malloc`. Symetrically, you should use `free` if an object has been created with a direct call to `malloc` in a C library.

Comment: @Olaf (and Serge) Once again, it's redundancy from the perspective that they both do the same thing. Yes, there might be systems-level reasons for using `malloc` over `new`, and yes, interface considerations (eg when using a C library) need to be respected. But at the level of the language itself, there is no need for `malloc` in C++. It is there solely to maintain C compatibility.

Comment: @davmac: fully agree with your last comment.

Comment: @davmac: finally: embedded systems is not the same as "system level". And maintaining C compatibility is nonsense, because the languages themselves are not compatible. But I agree that almost all usages in C++ are just a signal of bad design.

Comment: @Olaf you are nit-picking to the extreme. Please read "C compatibility" as "compatibility with some C code". Of course the languages are not fully compatible. Regarding "system level", if you are choosing `malloc` vs `new` because it is better on your target _system_ then it is a _system level_ concern that drives your decision.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't do implicit conversion of `void*` ...You will have to explicitly do it

```
char *p = static_cast<char*>(malloc(10));
```

or

```
char *p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(malloc(10));
```

Comment: @YSC I don't see the problem with `static_cast` and think it should be preferred in this case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Comment: BTW, why static_cast is not correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Although, many people think that everything done in C can be done in C++, with the nearly same code is wrong. C++ is not a superset of C. Both are different.

Thus, the compilers will be different and `g++` is used for C++ while `gcc` is used for C.

Check this: [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)