# Widening and narrowing rules in C/C++

Tags: c++, standards

I was trying to read through the C/C++ standard for this but I can't find the answer.

Say you have the following snippet:

```
int8_t m;
int64_t n;
```

And that at some point you perform `m + n`, the addition itself is a binary operator and I think the most likely think that happen in such a case is:

1. Wide `m` to the same size of `n`, call the widening result `m_prime`
2. Perform `m_prime + n`
3. Return a result of type `int64_t`

I was trying to understand however if instead of performing `m+n` I had performed `n+m` the result would change (because maybe there could be a narrowing operations instead of a widening).

I cannot find the part of the standard that clarify this point (which I understand it could sound trivial).

Can anyone point me where I can find this in the standard? or what happens in general in situations like the one I exposed?

Personally I've been looking at the section "Additive operators" but it doesn't seem to me to explain what happens, pointer arithmetic is covered a bit, but there's no reference to some casting rule implicitly applied.

You can assume I'm talking about C++11, but any other standard I guess would apply the same rules.

Comment: There is no `C/C++` standard. There's a `C` standard, an a `C++` standard. And the two are very different documents.

Comment: C is basically almost a true subset of C++, at least ANSI C89 is. And yes, you get widening regardless of whether the smaller integer is to the left or to the right of the + sign.

Comment: *"C is basically almost a true subset of C++, at least ANSI C89 is"* - That isn't true, I'm afraid.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I think that restricting to what I've asked they can be considered the same. I don't see why this specific part should change.

Comment: @StoryTeller. It is true. Note that I said 'almost'. All of K&R book examples (ANSI C89 version) compile with a C++ compiler. No two other languages I know of are that closely related.

Comment: Have a read on [Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), should explain pretty clearly what the rules are, references are in the footer.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Could you point out the reference? Other than experimenting probably.

Comment: Because if the two can have different rules for `const` propagation, they can also have different rules for widening/narrowing conversions (and they do, gcc & clang have only C++ specific flags for any such warnings).

Comment: @ErikAlapää -- You are [being misled and are misleading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505402/does-c-contain-the-entire-c-language). That "almost" is a very big fraction.

Comment: @user8469759: Maybe this will be enough? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc9te331(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @StoryTeller: For most practical purposes, C (ANSI C89) is a true subset of C++. There are many C++ haters who want to disassociate C with C++, therefore they do not like that the languages are so close.

Comment: @ErikAlapää - For the practical purpose of `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);` the two are not the same. That's valid (and actually good) `C` , and not valid `C++`. I don't hate on either. But I object to the notion one can just ignore the difference, it leads to sub-par programs and programmers.

Comment: Didn't he say C is for all practical purposed a subset of C++. Your example isn't a valid C++ program.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is a pretty good answer: (see the 'subset' question), https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Clause 5 Expressions [expr]. Point 10 starts

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a **common type**, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:

The sub-points that follow say things like "If **either** operand is...", "...the **other** shall...", "If **both** operands ..." etc.

For your specific example, see 10.5.2

> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.